# PLINQ and AsParallel()

Tags: c#, plinq

What is the difference between this code:

```
int[] tab = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

List<int> result1 = (from t in tab
                     where t > 2
                     select t).AsParallel().ToList();
```

and this:

```
List<int> result2  = (from t in tab.AsParallel()
                      where t > 2
                      select t).ToList();
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go back .....

[image]

There are two strategies for partitioning work among threads: data parallelism and
task parallelism.

Your are in : `structured data parallelism` zone. ( in plinq)

So the **DATA** which we deal with should be divided to threads.

Your first code is pointless.

Look at the syntax of AsParallel :

```
public static ParallelQuery AsParallel(
    this IEnumerable source
)
```

`AsParallel` should be applied on `IEnumerable` . ( like in both of your examples...but - )

The whole point here is to divide  work to threads .

This divides DATA to threads which perform the SAME operation.

In the second code you DO divide DATA to threads which will perform same operation. ( hence you get better performance)

But in the first code , the whole "making cores hot operation" is done in single thread. ( `where clause...`) - so you're missing the whole point

Notice - it would be worth something if :

```
...(from t in tab
    where t > 2
    select t).AsParallel().where(....)....
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything *after* a call to `AsParallel` will be parallelized.

So in your first listing only the `ToList` operation will be parallelized as where in the second code sample, the entire query will be parallelized.

Comment: And so the first one is nonsense.